# How to reconnect after a ServerDisconnectedError or ServerTimeoutError in "await asyncio.gather(*tasks)" when using aiohttp.ClientSession()?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

So, I'm trying to repeat a failed loop, because of errors such as ServerDisconnectedError and ServerTimeoutError, but I not getting it. Basically, what I'm doing is sending product codes to an endpoint that will return me some information about each one. I'm using asyncio.ensure_future to create the tasks and await asyncio.gather(*tasks) do the tasks (I'm not really familiar with asyncio and aiohttp functions, so I might be wrong in this explanation).

The ETL is running perfectly, the problem is the bigger is the chunk_size (amount of product code to be sent to the endpoint) the higher is the probability to get a ServerDisconnectedError or ServerTimeoutError during the loop. I can catch both of these two exceptions, the problem is, once I repeat the loop with "continue" it looks like the repeated loop doesnt work the properly (taking just a few time to send the same chunk of codes that took a good time running the first time), continually showing me the same excepetions I got the first time of the round. I don't know what to do, if I must reconnect the server once disconnected or anything else. I need to repeat the loop that failed and send again the chunk of product codes to the endpoint, as it did for the first time, in an attempt to acquire the information from this endpoint. Could anybody help with that? I hope I have been clear in the explanation of the problem.
So, this is the code:

````
async def get_all_balance(session, url, headers, product_code, company_code, balance_code):

    async with session.post(url,
                            data=json.dumps(
                                {'products': [product_code], 'companies': company_code, 'cdBalance': balance_code, 'inStock': 1, 'inSalesOrder': 1}),
                            headers=headers) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:

            data = await resp.read()
            product_balance = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))

            for data in product_balance['saldos']:
                lst_balance.append({
                    "cd_SKU": data.get('cdSKU'),
                    "cd_product": data.get('cdProduct'),
                    "cd_reference": data.get('cdReference'),
                    "cd_color": data.get('cdColor'),
                    "ds_size": data.get('dsSize'),
                    "cd_company": data.get('cdCompany'),
                    "nr_CNPJ_company": data.get('nrCNPJCompany'),
                    "qt_stock": data.get('qtStock'),
                    "qt_sales_order": data.get('qtSalesOrder'),
                    "cd_balance": codigo_balance
                })
        else:
            print("Resp.Status: {}".format(resp.status))

async def main():

    token = get_token() # Get a token to access the endpoint

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        lst_dict_cd_product = get_product_balance() # Get a list of dicts containing the product codes such as [{"cdProduto": "13889"}, {"cdProduto": "059788"}, ...]
        print("Qt products: " + str(len(lst_dict_cd_product)))

        tasks_balance = []

        lst_companies = [{"cdCompany": 1}, {"cdCompany": 2}, ...]

        lst_codigo_balance = [1, 11, 14]  # A balance code to be sent to the endpoint as a part of the payload

        chunk_size = 30000
        count = 0

        num_chunks = len(lst_dict_cd_product) / chunk_size
        mod_chunks = len(lst_dict_cd_product) % chunk_size
        # print(num_chunks)
        # print(mod_chunks)
        if mod_chunks != 0:
            print(int(num_chunks) + 1)
        else:
            print(int(num_chunks))

        for balance_code in lst_balance_code:

            if balance_code == 1:
                company_code= lst_companies[0:]
                print(company_code)
            else:
                company_code= lst_companies[0:1]
                print(company_code)

            for start in range(0, len(lst_dict_cd_product), chunk_size):
                end = start + chunk_size
                # print(lst_dict_cd_product[start:end])  # item chunks
                lst_product_code = lst_dict_cd_product[start:end]
                print("Chunks : {} of {} round {} s:e{}".format(
                    start, end, count, str(lst_codigo_product[0]) + ":" + str(lst_codigo_product[-1])))
                if count != 0:
                    time.sleep(60)
                k=0
                while k < 1:
                        for product_code in lst_codigo_product:
                            url = 'https://www30.bhan.com.br:9443/api/v1/produto/saldoproduto'
                            balance_tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(
                                get_all_balance(session, url, headers, product_code, company_code, balance_code)))  # emp_all[0:]
                        try:
                            await asyncio.gather(*balance_tasks)
                            count += 1
                            k += 1
                        except Exception as e:
                            continue

            # Save a json file
asyncio.run(main())
```python
````

Answer (score -1):

Make an infinite loop:

```
import time

connection = None

while(True):
    connection = try_connect()
    if connection:
        break # Get out of the loop.

    time.sleep(2) # Seconds.

do_someting(connection)
```

EDIT:

```
def try_connect():
    try:
        connection = ... # get connection.
    except [failed_connection_exception_type]:
        return False
    else:
        return connection
```

EDIT 2:
Short version

```
import time

connection = None
while(True):
    try:
        connection = ... # get connection.
    except [exception_type_to_catch]:
        time.sleep(2) # Seconds.
        continue
    else:
        break

do_someting(connection)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate your help. I'm using: "async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:" to connect with the server. Should I do what you suggested, in this case, like this: "success = async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:"?

Comment: I think I gave you everything you need. 1. How to loop indefinitely. 2. How to try/except, to keep iterating in the loop.  From there you will have to finish the job on your own. Good luck. ;)

Comment: The loop works, the problem is when you reach the line "await asyncio.gather(*balance_tasks)". The first time of the running, the function takes around 5 minutes and then python shows or "ServerDisconnectedError" or "ServerTimeoutError", one of them. However, when you catch this exception and repeat the failed loop again, when you reach the same line again "await asyncio.gather(*balance_tasks)", the function this time takes only 40-50 seconds to execute and python shows rightaway "ServerDisconnectedError" or "ServerTimeoutError".

Comment: It's like python doens't send the same chunk of product codes (30000) to the server or the server identifies the same call of product codes and understand as an invasion (I don't know), disconnecting me from the server. That's what it looks like

Comment: You are right. Repeating the loop won't do... Once disconnected, it must be re-established. There must be a connection time option somewhere. If you first try to do a simple/quick process (replacing balance_tasks with something trivial) does it works well?

Comment: I tried to reduce the size of the chunk of product codes, from 30000 to only 10 (just the first 10 product codes of the chunk of 30000 product codes), but I still get the "ServerDisconnectedError". I also tried to close the client of "async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client" with "await client.close()" and open it again after to failed loop, but didn't work as well.